# Routing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am upgrading an app from 3.2.4 to Rails 4 In my previous version i used:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
match ':controller(/search)(.:format)' => ':controller#search'
```

Now im getting an error

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:239:in `default_controller_and_action': 
':controller' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

I have about 10 to 15 different controllers that all use search.  Is there away I can use a similar code instead of writing each  controller to match `controller#search` ?

Answer (score 2):

I would just loop over all the controllers in an array and define each one dynamically like this:

```
%w(controller1 controller2 controller3).each do |controller_name|
  match "#{controller_name}(/search)(.:format)" => "#{controller_name}#search", via: :get
end
```

Note that you now need to add the `via` option that was not previously required. I assumed your search was via a GET request, but it might be via POST instead.

An added benefit of this approach is now if you inspect your routes, you will see exactly which ones are defined, and there is no guessing:

```
GET        /controller1(/search)(.:format)         controller1#search
GET        /controller2(/search)(.:format)         controller2#search
GET        /controller3(/search)(.:format)         controller3#search
```

Comment: Thank you Beerlington. This approach to this problem has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Second line is redundant because

```
match ':controller(/search)(.:format)' => ':controller#search'
```

covered in

```
match ':controller(/:action)(.:format)'
```

that is basically your first line route definition.

From Rails documentation in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

> Rails 4.0 requires that routes using match must specify the request
>   method.

So your routes should look like this

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: :get
```

or this

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Comment: your solutions still gives me the error: `default_controller_and_action': ':controller' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.`

Comment: Looks like your second declaration is redundant. First line covers `GET  /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action` that is what you want to say by your second line. Another words your second line may be written as `get ':controller(/:action)(.:format)'`

Comment: ... or second line may be just omitted. I modified my answer above.